# php foreach sort before results

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

i have searched the forums but am not able to solve this problem:

i have a selection which displays Manufacturers names.
this is working correctly, but all names are not in sort-order.

this is my code:

```
<select name="manufacturer_id" id="manufacturer_id" data-inline = "true" style="width: 8.4em;">
              <option <?php if(!isset($brand)) { echo 'selected="yes"' ; } ?> ></option>
              <?php foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>
              <?php if ($manufacturer['manufacturer_id'] == $manufacturer_id) { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $manufacturer['manufacturer_id']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></option>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $manufacturer['manufacturer_id']; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></option>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php } ?>
              </select>
```

is there any way to sort the output? or can someone point me in the right direction?

thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: Since you say that you've searched, what have you tried? In what way did it not work?

Comment: i tried the sort() function, ksort, asort, so i think i am doing something wrong with syntax or placement of the sorting function. I can obviously place all the code i created, but it seemed better to post the code that works and this way it won't create an almost impossible post.

Comment: So show what you've tried, what the expected results were, and what the actual results were.

Comment: <?php ksort($brands);foreach ($manufacturers as $manufacturer) { ?>  same with normal sort(), also within own php tags like <?php ksort($brands) ?> <?php foreach... and no results..display is still the same. i tried different places

Comment: If you're sorting `$brands` but displaying `$manufacturers`, do you really expect `$manufacturers` to be sorted? `$manufacturers !== $brands`

Comment: i tried $brands $manufacturers $manufacturer_id, the whole lot. Why do you think i am asking for help here? No negative intent here, but isn't it more easy to help then to ask the obvious?

Comment: It's amazing how many people don't mention the obvious when asking a question, which is why we ask people to say what they've tried.... or at the very least (in this case) it would have been useful to see what your array actually looked like

Comment: Hi Mark, i will keep that in mind for the next time! I thought the code would speak for itself, but now i understand some more info to a question could be helpfull for those who can or are willing to answer. As newbie good lesson learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is a 2-d array.... sort works on a 1-d array

Use

```
usort(
    $manufacturers,
    function($a, $b) {
        return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
    }
)
```

Comment: Wow mark, thanks for the answer. i tried this one to, but probably with wrong syntax. It's working perfectly!